# how to generate instances ground truth for kitti dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-segmentation, object-detection-api, kitti

I am working on Instance segmentation using Tensorflow Object detection API on Kitti dataset.

In the Kitti dataset, I have the ground truth instances only for first set of images(xxxxxx_10.png) and not for the second set of images(xxxxxx_11.png).
I want to generate the ground truth for these images too.

How can I do it with the data I already have, like pair of Images, ground truth flow(only for first set of images), ground truth instances (only for first set of images).

Any leads on this would be really helpful.